# 回答にどのぐらい「マイナス投票」が続くと回答が受け付けられなくなるのでしょうか

Tags: サポート

最近、私の回答にマイナス投票が続いています。このままでは「自動フィルタ」により回答が禁止されるのではないかと心配しています。
具体的にはどのぐらいで回答ができなくなるかを知りたいです。

以下はヘルプ センター > 回答にあたってからの引用です。

> [私のアカウントからの回答が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)
>
> Stack Exchange には、過去に低品質の回答を多数投稿したアカウントからの回答を禁止するために、自動フィルターが設置されています。このようなフィルターにより、サイトの品質は高く保たれています。禁止するための正確な算出式は公開されていませんが、ユーザーが禁止されるのは、反対票が多数投票されたり、投票がゼロであったり、削除されたりした投稿が多数あった場合のみです。悪い投稿が 1、2 あっただけでは、サイトの使用をブロックされることはありません。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

そのヘルプページに書かれているとおり、**禁止するための正確な算出式は公開されていません**。[Meta Stack Exchange に投稿されている FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/341401) も確認してみましたが、やはり公開されていませんでした。ただ、仮に BAN されることになったとしてもすぐ BAN されるのではなく一度警告として数日間だけ BAN されるので、それで知ることができるようです。

---

ところでここからは個人的な感想ですが、akira さんのご投稿を簡単に見てみたところ、他の方の投稿と比べて特筆たくさんマイナス投票されるようなクオリティのものには思えませんでした。何故度々ちょっとだけマイナス投票されているのか謎です。もし私がこのような状況になったらどういう行動をしそうか考えてみました。

- マイナス投票されている投稿を改善する。マイナス投票されたのは誰かの琴線に触れたからでしょう。同じように、誰かの琴線に触れてプラス投票されるように投稿を編集してみます。

  - 「試してみた」系の投稿は、何故その「試してみた」を回答として投稿する意味があるのか、理由を付記して分かりやすくする。たとえば[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/61838/19110)は質問者さんの手元の結果がおかしくないことを示すために自分の手元でのベンチマーク実行結果を参考として出したのだと思いますが、早とちりな方は最初の1行だけ読んで回答ではない投稿だと思いマイナス投票をされるかもしれません。自分の実行結果は回答の後ろの方に回して、回答として言いたいことである「おかしくない」「なぜなら～」の部分を先に書くと誤解されにくくなりそうです。また、そうすることで回答として読みやすくなり、プラス投票を誘発しやすくなるでしょう。
  - [この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/62235/19110)のように「間違ってはいないのだけどエレガントさにかける」系の投稿は、その方法が補足であることを追記するか、短所を補う長所があることを追記する。このような投稿はそもそも[マイナス投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)されるべきでないのですが、プラス投票もしにくいので誰かのマイナス投票が残ったままになりがちです。そこで、マイナス投票しにくくしたりプラス投票しやすくするのがひとつの方策になります。すぐにはプラス投票されないかもしれませんが、その回答が残っている意味があるなら、いずれ同じ境遇の方からプラス投票されることでしょう。
- 投稿を改善する方法をメタで聞く。どうしてもマイナス投票の意図が分からない場合、メタで意見を乞うことができます。特に、よっぽどたくさんマイナス投票されたもののその意図が分からないときに有用です。
- 嫌がらせの可能性を考える。もしかしたら、誰か特定のユーザーから繰り返しマイナス投票されているのかもしれません。しかし、スタック・オーバーフローではそのようなことをしているユーザーを自動検知する仕組みを[整えており](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27535/341401)、可能性は低いのではないかと推測します。もしよっぽど大量のマイナス票が投じられてどうしても疑惑が拭いきれずメタでも解決しなければ、[問い合わせフォーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)から Stack Exchange の社員に調査を依頼します（誰が投票を入れたかはモデレーターでも分からない情報なので、社員レベルの権限が無いと分かりません）。――[ハンロンの剃刀](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%89%83%E5%88%80)も時々思い出します。

Comment: 「禁止するための正確な算出式は公開」されておらず、どのぐらいで回答できなくなるかはわからないことを理解しました。もし回答が禁止された場合にはどのようなことができるのか、心積もりができました。もう回答禁止については心配しないようにします。「特筆たくさんマイナス投票されるようなクオリティのものには思えませんでした。」との感想をいただき、とても気が楽になりました。｢マイナス投票｣のおかげ(?)で自分の回答を見直す契機になったこと、無頓着に回答していた姿勢を見直すきっかけになったことも事実です。前向きに考えようと思います。また、いただいた「感想」は、回答の質を上げるための具体的なアドバイスと受け止めました。こちらも感謝します。nekketsuuu♦さん、ありがとうございました。